# python regex specific blocks of text from large text file

Tags: performance

I'm new to python and this site so thank-you in advance for your... understanding. This is my first attempt at a python script.

I'm having what I think is a performance issue trying to solve this problem which is causing me to not get any data back.

This code works on a small text file of a couple pages but when I try to use it on my 35MB real data text file it just hits the CPU and hasn't returned any data (>24 hours now).

Here's a snippet of the real data from the 35MB text file:

```
D)dddld
d00d90d
dd

ddd

vsddfgsdfgsf

dfsdfdsf
aAAAAAa

221546
29806916295
Meowing
fs:/mod/umbapp/umb/sentbox/221546.pdu
2013:10:4:22:11:31:4

sadfsdfsdf
sdfff
ff
f

29806916295
What's your cat doing?
fs:/mod/umbapp/umb/sentbox/10955.pdu
2013:10:4:22:10:15:4

aaa
aaa
aaaaa
```

What I'm trying to copy into a new file:

```
29806916295
Meowing
fs:/mod/umbapp/umb/sentbox/221546.pdu
2013:10:4:22:11:31:4

29806916295
What's your cat doing?
fs:/mod/umbapp/umb/sentbox/10955.pdu
2013:10:4:22:10:15:4
```

My Python code is:

```
import re

with open('testdata.txt') as myfile:
    content = myfile.read()

text = re.search(r'\d{11}.*\n.*\n.*(\d{4})\D+(\d{2})\D+(\d{1})\D+(\d{2})\D+(\d{2})\D+\d{2}\D+\d{1}', content, re.DOTALL).group()
with open("result.txt", "w") as myfile2:
    myfile2.write(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex isn't the fastest way to search a string. You also compounded the problem by having a very big string (35MB). Reading an entire file into memory is generally not recommended because you may run into memory issues.

Judging from your regex pattern, it seems like you want to capture 4-line groups that start with an 11-digit string and end with some time-line string. Try this code:

```
import re

start_pattern = re.compile(r'^\d{11}$')
end_pattern   = re.compile(r'^\d{4}\D+\d{2}\D+\d{1}\D+\d{2}\D+\d{2}\D+\d{2}\D+\d{1}$')

capturing = 0
capture   = ''

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if capturing > 0 and capturing <= 4:
                capturing += 1
                capture   += line                
            elif start_pattern.match(line):
                capturing = 1
                capture   = line

            if capturing == 4:
                if end_pattern.match(line):
                    output_file.write(capture + '\n')
                else:
                    capturing = 0
```

It iterates over the input file, line by line. If it finds a line matching the `start_pattern`, it will read in 3 more. If the 4th line matches the `end_pattern`, it will write the whole group to the output file.

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you very much for the answer!